# Expecation value of money in binomial distributed game

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I am having trouble finding the expectation value of the following.

> We play a betting game on the weather, $80\%$ of the days it rains, $20\%$ of the days it doesn't rain. In this case betting on rain is the optimal strategy, say I start with money $m=1$ and with this strategy I would obviously bet a fraction $b$ of my money every time. I am getting mixed answers on the expectation value of my money after $n=30$ games $\ldots$

My first guess is that I expect to win $0.8\cdot30=24$ times, thus expect to have $$E[m]=(1+b)^{24}(1-b)^6$$ after $30$ games, taking the derivative would allow me to find my optimal betting fraction.However I also reason that I can use the following model to get my expectation value

\begin{align} 
E[m] & = \sum_{k=0}^{30}(1+b)^k(1-b)^{30-k}{30 \choose k}0.8^k0.2^{30-k} = (1+0.6b)^{30}
\end{align}

These values are obviously not the same, this one is maximised for $b = 1$, which makes no sense since one loss would bankrupt me. But here I just used $E[m] = \sum m(x) P[X=x]$. With $m(x)$ the money I would have with $x$ wins, and $P$ the probability of $x$ wins.

Which of the two values is right, and where is my reasoning going wrong? I would expect both approaches to reach the same conclusion... Common sense tells me that the first answer is right, but I cant figure out why...

Comment: Assuming the outcomes are independent, betting all your money every time has the two effects of (a) maximising your expected return and (b) maximising the probability you lose all your money.  If your utility for money is non-linear (you seem horrified that you might lose everything) then maximising your expected return may not maximise your expected utility.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but this question was asked part of a probability exercise without any knowledge of utility. Are you saying both answers are correct but they are calculating different things?

Comment: I do not agree with your first approach, (I did not check the second) and the reason is the following: If you bet a b% of 1 in the first game, and say you win, then in the second game you will want to bet a fraction (possible again b%) of $1+b$ and not of $1$. Similarly if you lose. I think the second approach has the same problem, but I am not sure

Comment: Dynamic programming is the way to solve this kind of game, starting from the last day and maximizing your expected returns. On the last day, you maximize your expected return by betting all the money you have on rain. But, this is not necessarily true for the days before.

Comment: If you bet on rain every day for 30 days, your chance of being right is (.8)^30, and the payoff is 2^29 (not 2^30), for an expected value of ~664614. In all other cases, you lose everything. @Henry believes this is the best strategy if you always bet "b%" of your money (remember, the amount of money you have changes each time), and I tend to agree. However, if you're willing to bet a different amount of money each time (based on your current bankroll), the problem becomes more interesting.

Comment: @barrycarter I would have thought your payoff after 30 successful even-money bets was $2^30$ though possibly subtracting your original bankroll  of $1$

Comment: @Henry You're right, I'm wrong. For some reason, I was thinking 2^(n-1) money on day n, but that's BEFORE you bet. After you bet and win, it is indeed 2^n. So, the expected value would be 1.6^30 ~ 1329228. Hopefully, at least my reasoning was correct.